# Change FeatureCollection into Multipolygon

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine

I have code that works with features that are multipolygons.
The problem is that I want to work with shapefile that I upload, but it's always FeatureCollection and my code fail for this.I have see nthere is a code to make geometry into featurecollection but I want to other direction.

When I draw the polygons manualy it works.
Here you can see the differnce:

[image]

The first one is my uploaded shapefile and the second one is the manualy drawn shape.

**My end goal: To change my shapefile into multipolygon.**

*I dont add any code because I don't have code for this and I haven't found any way to do this,yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the geometry of a feature collection by using the `.geometry()` function.

`var my_fc_geometry = my_fc.geometry();`

Comment: that works, but now I see it changes it to polygon and not to multipolygon, is there any way to change it into multipolygon?